# If record exist disabled button in laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to disable a button if I have a user registered in my user table, but with the method that I am using does not inactivate the button that I want to be inactive, it is inactivating it to all the registers.

This is my user migration:

```
public function up()
{ 
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('id_employee')->unsigned();
        $table->string('username')->unique();//Cedula
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('password', 60)->nullable();
        $table->string('email', 60)->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();                  
        $table->foreign('id_employee')->references('id')->on('employees')
              ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

And this is my user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employees';

    protected $fillable = ['doc_number', 'user_code', 'name', 'last_name', 'settlement', 'address', 'city' , 'zip_code', 'email', 'phone', 'position', 'departments_id', 'hire_date'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Department');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }

    //Query para buscador
    public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
      $query->leftJoin('departments','employees.departments_id','=','departments.id')
            ->select('employees.*','departments.id as deptID','departments.name as department')
            ->where('employees.name','like',"%$name%")
            ->orWhere('employees.last_name','like',"%$name%")
            ->orWhere('employees.position','like',"%$name%")
            ->orWhere('employees.email','like',"%$name%")
            ->orWhere('employees.doc_number','like',"%$name%")              
            ->orWhere('departments.name','like',"%$name%"); 
    }
}
```

This is my index method controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $employees = Employee::name($request->get('criteria'))->orderBy('name','asc')->paginate(6);

        $departments = Department::orderBy('id', 'desc')->pluck('name', 'id');

        $users = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->pluck('username', 'id');

        return view('employees.index', compact('employees', 'departments', 'users'))
        ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 6);
    }
```

And this is my blade view with button:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group">                                     
        @if(count($users) === 0)
        <a href="{{ URL::route('padron.create', $employee->id) }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Confirmar votante">Confirmar</a>

        @else
            <a type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" disabled="disabled" title="Confirmar votante">Confirmar</a>

        @endif
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Your purpose does not seem clear. Do you want to disable a form for a logged in user? And enable it only for non registered /not logged in users?

Comment: I want to disable the button if I have one of those records in my users table.

Comment: Check with `auth()` or `Auth` for what you want and compare it with the data in the users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Send a value back with you successful return statement in controller function
2. and check if that value exists in your view with this

Answer (score 1):

In plain English, your logic reads, if there are no users, show the button, else disable the button. It seems you have `users`, therefore the if always fail and the else comes in play.

If you want to disable 'confirmar' for a single button, you will have to use the user's id somewhere. Something like

```
@if($employee->id == ...) 
// depending on your logic
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not from the table of employees that I want to confirm, it is from the users table, what happens is that there is a process that creates a user of employees.

If this user is created, then the button must be disabled.